# The HTTP server could not start check that the port is not in use

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

When i run my apache tomcat server in Netbeans I get this error: `The HTTP server could not start check that the port is not in use`. and one more errror is getting  port 8080 is in use , but 8080 is actually not using .

Can any say why this problem.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to check if the something is using the port

```
netstat -an | grep 8080
```

if yes then check the most notorious services that uses the same port

http://www.sitepoint.com/unblock-port-80-on-windows-run-apache/

Comment: But rav , the actual problem is  the error "The HTTP server could not start check that the port is not in use"

Comment: @user3007314 Check if _something else_ is on that port…